# How do you use the Android Debugger?

Tags: android, debugging

I find it really difficult to make anything from all the stuff that the debugger shows. I can't manage to find out where the program would be at. In Java, it was much simpler to follow code line by code line what is happening. Does anyone know how I could learn it quickly?

Comment: What do you mean? It is exactly the same if you're using eclipse to debug Android as it is to debug a normal java app.

Comment: lets put it this way. I use Java on NetBeans so the debugging is different that of Eclipse. How can I follow line by line? I can't see which line would be being handled by the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like you can use this plugin:
http://kenai.com/projects/nbandroid
which is for netbeans if you are already familiar with netbeans